# How do I fix the ResourceExhaustedError: Traceback (most recent call last)/2 root error(s) found errors I am getting

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am working on an ESPCN model and I tried to build it like this,

```
upscale_factor = 3
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 1))
conv1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 5, activation="tanh", padding="same")(inputs)
conv2 = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="tanh", padding="same")(conv1)
conv3 = layers.Conv2D((upscale_factor*upscale_factor), 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(conv2)
outputs = tf.nn.depth_to_space(conv3, upscale_factor, data_format='NHWC')
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

def gen_dataset(filenames, scale):
    crop_size_lr = 128
    crop_size_hr = 128 * scale

    for p in filenames:
        image_decoded = cv2.imread("Training/DF2K/"+p.decode(), 3).astype(np.float32) / 255.0
        imgYCC = cv2.cvtColor(image_decoded, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
        cropped = imgYCC[0:(imgYCC.shape[0] - (imgYCC.shape[0] % scale)),
                  0:(imgYCC.shape[1] - (imgYCC.shape[1] % scale)), :]
        lr = cv2.resize(cropped, (int(cropped.shape[1] / scale), int(cropped.shape[0] / scale)),
                        interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        hr_y = imgYCC[:, :, 0]
        lr_y = lr[:, :, 0]

        numx = int(lr.shape[0] / crop_size_lr)
        numy = int(lr.shape[1] / crop_size_lr)
        for i in range(0, numx):
            startx = i * crop_size_lr
            endx = (i * crop_size_lr) + crop_size_lr
            startx_hr = i * crop_size_hr
            endx_hr = (i * crop_size_hr) + crop_size_hr
            for j in range(0, numy):
                starty = j * crop_size_lr
                endy = (j * crop_size_lr) + crop_size_lr
                starty_hr = j * crop_size_hr
                endy_hr = (j * crop_size_hr) + crop_size_hr

                crop_lr = lr_y[startx:endx, starty:endy]
                crop_hr = hr_y[startx_hr:endx_hr, starty_hr:endy_hr]

                hr = crop_hr.reshape((crop_size_hr, crop_size_hr, 1))
                lr = crop_lr.reshape((crop_size_lr, crop_size_lr, 1))
                yield lr, hr
import os

filenames = os.listdir("Training/DF2K/")
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        gen_dataset, (tf.float32, tf.float32), (tf.TensorShape([None, None, 1]), tf.TensorShape([None, None, 1])),
        args=[filenames, upscale_factor]).batch(32).shuffle(buffer_size=5000)

def PSNR(y_true, y_pred):
    max_pixel = 1.0
    return tf.image.psnr(y_true, y_pred, max_val=max_pixel)

opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(
    learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss='mse', 
              metrics=[PSNR])

model.fit(ds, epochs=60, verbose=2)
```

But when I try to train the model I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11332/3038405447.py in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(ds, epochs=60, verbose=2)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\gpu2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     56   try:
     57     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 58     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     59                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     60   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED:  MemoryError: Unable to allocate 35.6 MiB for an array with shape (1524, 2040, 3) and data type float32
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 275, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 649, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 992, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11332/1792224485.py", line 7, in gen_dataset
    image_decoded = cv2.imread("Training/DF2K/"+p.decode(), 3).astype(np.float32) / 255.0

numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 35.6 MiB for an array with shape (1524, 2040, 3) and data type float32


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.

     [[gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/Shape_5/_10]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.

  (1) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED:  MemoryError: Unable to allocate 35.6 MiB for an array with shape (1524, 2040, 3) and data type float32
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 275, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 649, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 992, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "C:\Users\TanveerU\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11332/1792224485.py", line 7, in gen_dataset
    image_decoded = cv2.imread("Training/DF2K/"+p.decode(), 3).astype(np.float32) / 255.0

numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 35.6 MiB for an array with shape (1524, 2040, 3) and data type float32


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_752]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

I brought down the batch size to 8 and the buffer_size to 5000 from 64 and 10000 respectively but still am facing this issue. The dataset is the DF2K dataset(~15Gb) and am using my personal computer with the GTX 1650 GPU.
Thank you for reading this and helping me :)

Comment: First check the GPU status for the actual memory consumption as at repeated runs of the process can cause the exhausting of GPU memory not garbagecollecting the memory what it used before. It may rerun without any issue at rerun once the memory consumption shows 0%.
If it is ok, and still have the issue, first aff all go down to batch size 1 checking if the model paramaters fit into the GPU memory.

Comment: I checked the parameters and they fit in the GPU memory when the batch size is 1. Yet I am unable to go ahead with any other batch size.

Comment: Ok, what is the memoryconsumption based on the paramaters?

Comment: There are 22,800 parameters. When I put the batch size to 4 and start training the model, I used
``` import GPUtil
GPUtil.show.Utilization() ``` and the Mem usage shows to be 77% and the GPU usage was 27%. Sorry for the late reply, I have Covid and unable to work.

Comment: No problem, and be healthy soon! Not clear if here the "Mem usage" means the GPU mem and the GPU usage stands for GPU utilization. If so, the max batch size can not be more the 5. Furthermore my experience is, that after repeated rerun of the process the garbage collection can be insufficient, so please try to reboot your machine and rerun the training in that "blank" state and check the GPU cunsumption data that way also.